# How to structure database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore and have a profile collection where each document consists of this model:

```
User
  - First name
  - Last Name
  - Bio
  - CreatedAt
  - Profile Pic
    - Location
    - Type
```

Now a user can record a video of a stream between two people. This video is stored and needs to be accessible by the two streaming people when they view their profile.

My plan is to have a separate collection called "Videos" where each video is as such:

```
Video
  - PersonAId
  - PersonBId
  - url
  - thumbnail
```

My first question is, should I be storing these in a separate collection, or should I just add the video to a "video" subcollection under each person's User model?

Secondly, I need to get the `First name` + `Last name` of `PersonAId` and `PersonBId`. Obviously one of those IDs is gonna be the user who's retrieving the video, so I will have their name, but will I then need to make a database call for the other ID in each video? Or is there an easier way to do that like being able to join collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a separate collection for video, as it needed to be accessed by both. So why to create two entries, also separate collection would be easy to maintain and making query would at the easy approach.

I haven't seen any joins in their documentation, it's in dev pipeline.